# configuring SAMBA for reasonable auditing

Tags: rhel, samba, samba4

Can someone post an `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file that has configuring that will provide **reasonable** logging and audit information into a log file?  My efforts thus far, in RHEL 8.9, have amounted to 98% stuff I do not wish to see and the 2% I do see falls short of being interpret-able.

Is it possible to have **just** the following information in a samba log file?

- date & time of any initial connection over the network, from a win10 client connecting to the linux samba server, and if successful or not

  - ip address of the client connection and the windowsNT user name, for both a successful and an unsuccessful connection
- then for a successful connections into the samba server, log the folder tree traversal of the user for both successful and unsuccessful attempts to what they try to access

  - same for file accesses: log creations, deletions, save or modify attempts and permission changes on files & folders